# Как изменить цвет SVG изображения

Tags: html, css3, html5, svg, svg-спрайт

[image: Так это выглядит в браузере]

Все заданные стили в котором находиться изображение.
Эти стили написаны в .scss

```
    .section-wrap {
    position: relative;

    .section-wrap__icon {

        a {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            position: absolute;left: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 8%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 15px);
            z-index: 2;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: $white;
        }

        .section-wrap__img {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            fill: $red; // #e74c3c;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

    }

}
```

Подключенное изображение через HTML

```
<div class="section-wrap__icon">
  <a href="#">
  <img class="section-wrap__img img" src="img/icons/icon1.svg">
  </a>
  </div>
```

SVG-файл

```
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="icon1.svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 474.986 474.986" style="enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_3_" d="M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577
    l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902
    c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343
    c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789
    c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353
    c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771
    c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036
    l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086
    c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327
    c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854
    c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008
    c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839
    c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514
    C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Цветовые переменные, которые я использовал. Файл _variables.scss

```
$white: #fff;
$black: #000;

$white-gray: #f4f5f9;
$gray-light: #cbc6c0;

$red: #e74c3c;
```

Comment: Может как то через JS?

Comment: если верстку поменять нельзя, то только через js ну или в svg поменять

Comment: Каким образом? Можно пример пожалуйста.

Comment: так верстку поменять нельзя или можно?

Comment: А чем вас `fill` не устраивает?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Вы в своем ответе не указали как этот css применить (то что его нужно добавить в svg)

Comment: Обновил, может теперь это поможет.

Comment: Верстку изменить нельзя, вопрос обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если можно поменять цвет в самой иконке - то вот

```
 <path id="XMLID_3_" fill="red"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="icon1.svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 474.986 474.986" style="enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_3_" fill="red" d="M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577
    l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902
    c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343
    c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789
    c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353
    c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771
    c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036
    l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086
    c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327
    c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854
    c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008
    c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839
    c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514
    C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z"/>
   
</svg>
```

PS: Если же верстку поменять нельзя, а иконки из основного документа хочется раскрасить по-разному уже необходимо по колдовать:

```js
addToDom('.section-wrap__img')

function addToDom(selector) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(el => {
    fetch(el.src).then(r => r.text()).then(r => {
      let p = el.parentNode;
      el.remove();
      p.innerHTML += r;
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.section-wrap__icon2 path {
  fill:red;
}

.section-wrap__icon1 path {
  fill:blue;
}

svg{
  width:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrap__icon2">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="section-wrap__img img" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='icon1.svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 474.986 474.986' style='enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_3_' fill='red' d='M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577 l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902 c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343 c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789 c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353 c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771 c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036 l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086 c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327 c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854 c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008 c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839 c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514 C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="section-wrap__icon1">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="section-wrap__img img" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='icon1.svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 474.986 474.986' style='enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath id='XMLID_3_' fill='red' d='M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577 l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902 c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343 c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789 c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353 c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771 c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036 l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086 c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327 c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854 c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008 c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839 c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514 C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
  </a>
</div>
```

PS: скачиваем svg и добавляем ее на место `<img>`, классы не переносил...

Comment: Нет, это не сработало

Comment: @FrencOlesov куда Вы и что добавили в Ваш код?

Comment: Тогда давайте колдовать с помощью JS. У меня нет представлений на этот счет.

Comment: В icon1.svg к path. Но, это сработало.